# Is there a way to animate in flutter to a specific offset in a horizontal scrollview?

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to animate to a specific point in the listview after the user stopped scrolling. But somehow, it doesn't work when I use `_controller.animateTo(<parameters>)` in my `NotificationLister<ScrollEndNotification>`. However, it does work when I use ScrollUpdateNotification but in this case this is useless.

```
Positioned(
          right: 15,
          top: 80,
          width: 180,
          height: 40,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
            child: NotificationListener<ScrollEndNotification>(
              onNotification: (ScrollEndNotification sn){
                _controller.animateTo(60, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.linear);
                return true;
              },
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: currencies.length,
                itemBuilder: ((BuildContext ctxt, int index){
                  return Container(width: 60.0, child: Text(currencies[index].symbol, style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: 20),), alignment: Alignment.center);
                }),
                controller: _controller,
              ),
            )
          )
        ),
```

In short: I need to animate the offset of the ScrollView after the user stopped scrolling

Comment: Answer Updated - Please Check !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Code:

Change - `_controller.animateTo(60, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.linear);`

to

`_controller.animateTo(_controller.offset + 60, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.linear);`

***Update***  - we need to add few Milliseconds delay in order for this to work.

Working Code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //  backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 22, 22, 22),
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollEndNotification>(
        onNotification: (ScrollEndNotification sn) {
          print(scrollViewColtroller.position.userScrollDirection);
          Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
            if (scrollViewColtroller.offset != 60.0) {
              scrollViewColtroller.animateTo(100,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.linear);
        }
          });
          return true;
        },
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                  width: 50.0,
                  color: (i % 2) == 0 ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                    i.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ))),
            );
          },
          shrinkWrap: true,
          controller: scrollViewColtroller,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Output: Each time we scroll, we animate back to Container 2 after user scroll end.

[image]

Comment: Sadly, this didn't change anything. Do you need more code?

Comment: Perfect, Thank you.
Even tough its a bit pecuiliar. Btw. it also works with 1 milisecond

Comment: I use Future.microtask(). There's no need to have a delay to make it work.